# Printing query in HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just wondering if anyone would be able to help me with a problem I've been having. I'm trying to print data from a mysql query into an html table. I'm using a nested for loop and I'm very nearly there. I just can't seem to work out how to print more than one line of results. The code I have at the minute is:

```
$query = "select TeacherName, Age, Subject from Teacher WHERE schoolcode =" . $schoolcode; // Specifying the query and using the variable school code from the frontend HTML form to make it reusable

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid query"); //Running the query and storing it in result
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);  // gets number of rows in result table
$numcols = mysqli_num_fields($result);   // gets number of columns in result table
$field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result); // gets the column names from the result table
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

print "<table border=1><tr>";
for($x=0;$x<$numcols;$x++){
print "<th>" . $field[$x]->name . "</th>";
}
print "</tr>";

for($j=0; $j<$numrows; $j++) {   // for loop goes round until there are no rows left
 print "<tr>";
     for ($k=0; $k<$numcols; $k++) {    //  goes around until there are no columns left
        print "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>"; //Prints the data
  }
   print "</tr>";
}

print "</table>";

mysqli_close($con); 
 ?>
```

The code very nearly works and does print out the html table with correct results. The problem is that it prints out one row of results, then repeats this same row of results on the next row, rather than printing the next row of results which I want. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Many Thanks

Comment: That loop with the $k is wrong, it's doing the same thing over and over again. You're not advancing to the next row. You're never looping $row. I think. Put the fetch_array in a loop to advance through the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  for ($k=0; $k<$numcols; $k++) {    //  goes around until there are no columns left
        print "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>"; //Prints the data
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I need to make the code reusable so this is what I am looking for.  This works fine but for some reason it omits the first row of results and goes onto the second. Do you know why this is?

Comment: You probably have a rogue mysqli_fetch_array that's grabbing the first row before it gets to this while loop.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  There was one just above.  Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, can you mark my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 <table>
 <Tr><td>Teacher Name</td></tr>
 <?php 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   ?>
    <Tr><td><?=$row['TeacherName']?><td><tr>
  <?php
}
 ?>  
</table>
```

much cleaner code and much easy way to do it

Comment: I think you mean mysqli_fetch_assoc rather than fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

**Simply try this it will work :**

```
      $query = "select TeacherName, Age, Subject from Teacher WHERE schoolcode =" . $schoolcode;
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid query");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    <table>
     <tr>
    <td>Teacher Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
<td>Subject</td>
    </tr>
     <?php 
     do
    {
       ?>
        <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['TeacherName']; ?><td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Age']; ?><td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Subject']; ?><td>
    <tr>
      <?php
    }while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
     ?>  
    </table>
```

Comment: I think you mean mysqli_fetch_assoc. And there are now 3 answers to the question that basically all say the same thing.

Comment: @Halfstop, yes use `mysqli_fetch_array` as you have a result in an array form.